# Clear the ng-model asssociated to textarea inside Angular Bootstrap UI tabset form an outside button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have used angular bootstrap ui `tabset` to create two tabs and both of the tabs have `textareas` associated with a `ng-model`, i have a clear button outside the `tabset` and i want to clear the `ng-model` of the `textArea` in active tab when user presses the clear button. what is the best way to do this? this is what i have done so far.

HTML

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab One">
        <textarea data-ng-model="data.tabOne" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab two">
        <textarea data-ng-model="data.tabOne" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </tab>
</tabset>
<button ng-click="clearFn()" class="btn btn-default btn-float-left">Clear</button>
```

Controller

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            tabOne: '',
            tabTwo: ''
        };

        $scope.ClearFn = function () {
            // I want to clear the model of the active tabs textArea here.
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tab's `active` attribute to find the current active tab.

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Tab One" active="activeState.tabOne">
    <textarea ng-model="data.tabOne" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab Two" active="activeState.tabTwo">
    <textarea ng-model="data.tabTwo" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

and in the controller:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    tabOne: 'ONE',
    tabTwo: 'TWO'
  };

  $scope.activeState = {};

  $scope.clearFn = function() {
    // I want to clear the model of the active tabs textArea here.
    for (var key in $scope.activeState) {
      if ($scope.activeState[key]) {
        // active tab found
        $scope.data[key] = '';
        return;
      }
    }
  };
}])
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ioJKua5XTeetBcvjGity?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since ng-model does a scope two way binding, in order to clear the ng-model, you can clear the scope variable.

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            tabOne: '',
            tabTwo: ''
        };

        $scope.ClearFn = function () {
            // I want to clear the model of the active tabs textArea here.
             $scope.data.tabOne ='';
           };
    }]);
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to clear the ng-model of the active tab. This way I can't determine the active tab right?