# Can't seem to get ng-model to work in this instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" id="hourHours" ng-model="hourHours" class="form-control" style="width: 60px" placeholder="hh" />
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="addSubscriptionModel()">submit</button>
```

Here's my simple html code with my ng-model. If I type in 5 into the input, the angular code should console.log out 5 but it's still undefined...

```
var SomeController = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.addSubscriptionModel = function () {
        console.log($scope.hourHours);
    }
});
```

EDIT: ACTUAL CODE... seems like I forgot to mention that I'm using tabset which might be why it's not working...

```
 <tabset>
     <tab heading="Hour" select="hourOption()" ng-model="hour">
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             <input type="text" id="hourHours" ng-model="hourHours" class="form-control" style="width: 60px" placeholder="hh" />
         </div>
     </tab>
 </tabset>
```

Comment: Where do you use this `console.log` statement? Can you provide the controller code as well?

Comment: Just did. Basically I press a button and it should log out the input...

Comment: And were is your button? Is it bound to `addSubscriptionModel`?

Comment: where/when are you defining the initial value for $scope.hoursHours. i.e.  $scope.hoursHours = 100; Can your provide a plnkr for this?

Comment: Added button and yes it has ng-click on it.
jeffrey - i'm not defining it initially. it's just a field in my ui and i need that field's value in angularjs. should i be defining values? normally i've never had to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite seeing enough detail here, but when your page loads and populates from a data source you typically need to set the properties on the model [scope] to initialize your page. In short what your are doing is a two way binding. So if you expect your page to be populated for before displaying then in your controller you need to set the values on the scope when the controller is executed. After your enter new data into your page the scope (or model), it will automatically be updated with the on screen values.

#### UPDATE

As a follow up.  I have learned the judicious use of `$compile` and `$interpolate` can go a long way to solving problems like.  They allow you to perform late bindings to the scope.  Also, while I still don't quite understand it fully understand when to use it, `transclusion` can also be helpful.

Comment: But why does it need to populate if I just need the user to input in data? In a tabset, the user enters in some data into an input field and I just need to get it on the angular side... there apparently is some issue getting ng-model to work with tabsets.

Comment: Ah TabSet. Indeed. I have had the same issue. Are you using Angular UI Bootstrap by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out...
[Clear the ng-model asssociated to textarea inside Angular Bootstrap UI tabset form an outside button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130595/clear-the-ng-model-asssociated-to-textarea-inside-angular-bootstrap-ui-tabset-fo)

Jeffrey A Gochin had the right idea... I did need to set "values" for my two objects inside my controller.

```
$scope.hour = {
    hours: "",
    minutes: ""
};
```

Then in my button function, I could access the $scope.hour and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code its working , check your console window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
  <head>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>




  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="MyCtrl">

   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" id="hourHours" ng-model="hourHours" class="form-control" style="width: 60px" placeholder="hh" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="addSubscriptionModel()">submit</button>
  </body>

</html>



<script>

  var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){


    $scope.addSubscriptionModel = function () {
        console.log($scope.hourHours);
    }


});

</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have... but it seems like it won't work on my version of the code.

Comment: but for me its working , better you check on the name of ng-app and ng-controller , are they proper???

Comment: added more code  - it seems like i forgot that it's in a tabset.

Comment: but its still working for me can you plz post your whole code or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: basically, i need to get information from the tabset (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Something with transclusion and $compile. I solved it by just including my form-ish content in the div tags rather than  trying to dynamically load them. You can read through the tabs code, and google the issue. There is no current fix other than the hack I described.

The crux of the problem is the need to $compile the tab content after it loads, but the current version of the tabs does not work properly. There is some recursion issue that causes a stack overflow under the wrong conditions.  There is an open issue on Git about it.